# How to fetch resultant of a POST request in a web-scraper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape out data from [this website.](http://ngo.india.gov.in/sector_ngolist_ngo.php?psid=&records=)

There is a table in which there are different organisations listed and the name each organisation is a link to a webpage with more information about the organisation.

Those links instead of being hard-coded hyperlinks they are call to javascript function which is computed when the function is called.

```
<a href="javascript:view_ngo('4309','','1','0')" class="bluelink11px">

BISWASUK SEVASRAM SANGHA    

</a>
```

So it is not possible to scrape out information by just following the links.

Is there any workaround to execute the javascript function and get the HTML of the resultant webpage? I am using Python 3, and using Beautiful Soup as web scraper.

Comment: You could try Selenium; that'll spin up a browser.

Comment: I think so it will increase the execution time. I have to go through 70,000 web pages. 

Serge gave a nice little solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the javascript will not be executed *server side* but always client side. Here, you should simply use the debugging facilities or a browser (Firefox function F12 is enough) to see what happens when you click on one of the links. You immediately see that the javascript code only prepares and send a POST request

So `view_ngo(a, b, c, d)` generates the following POST request:

```
POST http://ngo.india.gov.in/view_ngo_details_ngo.php
```

With the following data:

```
ngo_id=a&records_no=b&page_no=c&page_val=1&issueid=&ngo_black=d&records=
```

You can also see that it uses a session cookie, so you should take provisions for it in your scraping code.

Scraping could be like:

```
cookieProcessor = urllib.request.CookieProcessor()
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(cookieProcessor)
soup = BeautifulSoup(opener.open(
        'http://ngo.india.gov.in/sector_ngolist_ngo.php?psid=&records='))

# find the relevant links and iterate through them for view_ngo(a, b, c, d)

    data = urllib.parse.urlencode({'ngo_id': a, 'records_no': b, 'page_no': c,
        'page_val': '1', 'issue_id':'', 'ngo_black':d, 'records_no':'' }).encode()
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(opener.open('http://ngo.india.gov.in/view_ngo_details_ngo.php',
        data))
```